# Debugging Multiple web projects in Java/JEE

Tags: liferay-6

Team I have liferay Project say Project A which when built creates multiple wars. and is deployed in to Tomcat.

Now I have a project B which has dependency on the Project A (Via Tar ball of Project A)

Now i deploy project B into Tomcat.

Can anyone help me how can i debug through the code of project A as well 
Note that I use eclipse as ide and i have option of running tomcat in both IDE as well as from command prompt

Comment: A creates multiple wars and is deployed into tomcat. B is dependent on A via tarball: Please explain: Are they deployed as web applications? Does A have libraries that are included in B?

Comment: Yes they are deployed as Webapps and there are inter portlet dependencies i.e. A have libraries that are included in B